# How does CentOS (or Redhat-based) OS' construe file copies?

Tags: centos, rhel

General question regarding a copied file: Does CentOS (or RH-based) OS's append a 'space' and number to a file which already exists?

Example: If software is told to rename a file if a file with the same name already exists in the same directory, it will give it the same name but add a space and a number.

1/18/2022   fileA
1/19/2022   fileA 2

Comment: this isn't an OS feature, if anything it's a per-application feature. the default behaviour of a file copy at the OS level is to overwrite the destination

Comment: And why are you asking, i.e.: what is your specific problem?

Comment: @U.Windl my question is in regard to how an application on a CentOS server is reacting.  In order for me to troubleshoot, I wanted to know if this is an OS-specific function or software.  The vendor of the software informed me this is how their product works.  The OS is not creating the space and number by default.

Comment: Maybe better tell us what "software" is. You cannot expect an answer (other than "no") for such an abstract question.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The CentOS operating system is not by design constructed to append a space and number to a copy of a file in the same directory.  Software will determine how copies of existing files are renamed.